# App Engine AppID

Tags: google-app-engine

Ok, so this question is actually targeted at google, but since its impossible to get any kind of support ill try here. My company has a Google Apps Premium Account with a custom domain that is linked to App Engine. The account was created a long time ago when App Engine didnt have HRD option. The default application-name (coresponding to the custom domain) xxx.appspot.com was created using the old Master/Slave datastore, and therefore i set out to migrate it. First i migrated all to xxx-hrd and then deleted xxx.appspot.com so that i could re-create it again with HRD. My problem is now, that when i try to create xxx.appspot.com it tells me that the appid is not available. I then went through Google Apps and created it from there.. And that went fine.. But now it seems that the application has been created but no one has access to it. So where do i go from here ?

Comment: Are you sure google is not processing your demand ? How long did you wait before trying to access the domain ? (Just a logical question, I totally don't know google app engine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to google documentation, it's not possible to create the same app-id twice.

```
Once you register an application ID, you can delete it, 
but you can't re-register that same application ID after
it has been deleted. You can skip these next steps if you
don't want to register an ID at this time.
```

(That's the reason you can't create the application in GAE)

Probably the configuration in your apps account to access this app-id, it probably detects only the deleted app-id.

I would suggest to build a new app-id and connect these in your apps account.

It also usually takes a little time to get the connection working (as DNS entries are reconfigured and needs to be distributed). I had to wait a couple of hours.

Comment: Great.. :) ! Ill just use kobstaden-hrd.appspot.com . not optimal, but i guess that users wont see the appspot id anyways..

Comment: @JakobHarderHolmelund The migration process sets up an alias from the old appid to the new one. If you hadn't deleted the old app, it would have automatically been aliased to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Premier Account, did you try opening a case on the Enterprise Portal: https://enterprise.google.com/customerportal/ ??

I always get great service using that channel.